# ASP.Net Web API 404 Error on 2nd API

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

So I already have 1 Web API set up and working great, but now that I am trying to set up my own admin panel ( which I did ), I need to use the `DeleteUser()` function from the Web API named `AdminApi` but I can't seem to get it working. I keep getting 404 error while giving the path that the API should be at.

Web Api Config:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Global :

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    //Create the custom role and user
    RoleActions roleActions = new RoleActions();
    roleActions.AddUserAndRole();
}
```

AdminApi :

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
public class AdminApiController : ApiController
{
    public string test()
    {
        return "test";
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public string DeleteUser(string id)
    {
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var user = db.Users.Find(id);
        if (user != null)
        {
            string email = user.Email;
            db.Users.Remove(user);
            return "Succesfully deleted user : " + email;
        }
        else
            return "Failed to delete user.";
    }
}
```

Ajax :

```
function deleteUser (id)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: '../api/AdminApi/DeleteUser',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(id),
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (x, y, z) {
            alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
        }
    });
}
```

The ajax function is called on the page /Admin/AdminPage
so to get to the web api -> ../api/AdminApi
and the function to delete users is DeleteUser 
-> ../api/AdminApi/DeleterUser

I don't get why I get a 404 error. I can understand if my function `DeleteUser` is not working since I haven't tested it, but I can't test it if I can't get in the function.

Comment: Suggestion delete operation in WEBAPI should be "HttpDelete" avoid using post for delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related to how you use the attribute:

```
[Route("DeleteUser")]
```

If you use the Attribute **Route**. at Method level what it does is to define new route or more routes therefore the way you should use it is like `[Route('Url/path1/route1')]`:

As an example of how it works:

```
//GET api/customer/GetMetaData
[Route('/api/customer/GetMetaData')]
public string Get2(){
      //your code goes here
}
```

If you will be declaring several Routes in your class then you can use **RoutePrefix** attribute like `[RoutePrefix('url')]` at class level. This will set a new base URL for all methods your in Controller class.

For example:

```
[RoutePrefix("api2/some")]
public class SomeController : ApiController
{
    // GET api2/some
    [Route("")]
    public IEnumerable<Some> Get() { ... }

    // POST api2/some/DeleteUser/5 
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("DeleteUser/{id:int}")]
    public Some DeleteUser(int id) { ... } 

}
```

**Update**

By default Web API looks at the routing URL first, what is in your [Route] I mean and it tries to match it against your post. However if your method has a complex object  as parameter WebApi can't get the values from the request URI because the parameter is a complex type Web API uses a media-type formatter to read the value from the request body.

Since your `string id` is not a complex object and it is part of your `Route` WebApi expects it as part of your URL not the body. Try this instead:

```
[HttpPost]
public string DeleteUser([FromBody]string anotherName)
```

Comment: Sorry for that @Dalorzo , the [Route("DeleteUser")] was just a test after it was not working, just forgot to remove it before posting , still not working without it and still not working with the different routes your proposed.

Comment: Try this with in your code `DeleteUser([FromBody]string id)`

Comment: it worked.... Can you explain to me why [FromBody] fixes a 404 error?

PS: Looks like my deletion doesn't work tho, if you don't mind having a quick look at it, it returns "successfully deleted the user" but it still shows up on refreshing of the page.

Comment: thanks alot! made it work for the deletion, just needed to savechanges, it all makes sense now.